# System.UriFormatException in unit test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uri

In my test project, I have a ViewModel that needs to load a list of objects from a ressource file within the application :

```
    private List<XapBus> staticBusList = new List<XapBus>();

    public XapEditorViewModel(ObservableCollection<XapDevice> deviceList, ObservableCollection<XapBus> busList)
    {
        DeviceList = deviceList;
        BusList = busList;

        string imagePath = "pack://application:,,,/Settings/BusSettingsSourceItems.xml";
        System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo imageInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(imagePath));
        var stream = new StreamReader(imageInfo.Stream, false);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<XapBus>));
        staticBusList = (List<XapBus>)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

And in my test methods I initialise a ViewModel :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewModel_BusListIsNull_ReturnsFalse()
    {
        //Arrange
        XapEditorViewModel VM = new XapEditorViewModel();
        //Act
        VM.BusList = null;
        bool isOK = VM.AddBus(new XapBus());
        //Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(isOK);
    }
```

When I run tests, I got a System.UriFormatException.

I found an stackoverflow question that uses this :

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void OnTestInitialize()
    {
        UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
    }
```

I added it, but without success...

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you checked Uri class code? Maybe it does not use UriParser

Comment: How is it that the Vm constructor has arguments but in the test none are passed when initializing the subject?

Comment: Also the view model is tightly coupled to static implementation concerns that wont be available when uni-testing in isolation.

Comment: That view model appears to be violating SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and should be refactored to extract the presentation concerns being done in its constructor.

Comment: I have 2 constructors, one without arguments, I rewrite the code for this question to be clearer

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll move the static list population in presentation layer, And populate the static list in test method.